# I'm trying to delete a file in ubuntu and it fails

Tags: git, ubuntu, filesystems

[image: Error message]

I cloned a GitHub repo and I tried to delete it. But when I'm trying it this error occurred.

I also tried with the terminal using sudo but it failed too.
[image: Terminal screenshot]

What can be the real issue here?
These files are in my HDD and it's auto mounting when start the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325343/unable-to-delete-file-rm-cannot-remove-input-output-error

Seems like an issue with your external storage, you can try manual delete as well as suggested above.